# jquery adding form elements with square brackets

Tags: jquery, append, square-bracket

I'm trying to dynamically add hidden input fields to a form with square brackets in their id/name:

```
<input type="hidden" name="myField[]" id="myField[]" value="someValue" />
```

The adding works fine (at least firebug shows the correctly added fields). But when I try to access the post-array in the receiving PHP-script, the fieldnames end up being `myField%5B%5D` and the array is lost.

When such fields are added manually to the HTML-code, I end up having a nice array in my postvars.

How do I fix this?

[Edit]

This is how I add the fields:

```
$('#theForm').append(
                $('<input/>')
                    .attr('type', 'hidden')
                    .attr('name', 'myField[]')
                    .attr('id', 'myField[]')
                    .val(value)
            );
```

I also tried using escape characters like `\[\]` - and also `\\[\\]` - to no avail

Comment: Show us how you add them ?

Comment: Seems to work just fine for me, but for some reason the POST data is'nt urldecoded when you receive it ?

Comment: When I do a print_r($_POST) in the receiving script, the result is Array ( [myField%5B%5D] => someValue )
Expected would be Array ( [myField][] => someValue ) - As I said - the adding works fine - but the serialisation (serialize()) seems to fail

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read **[this](http://benalman.com/news/2009/12/jquery-14-param-demystified/)** and try this:

```
$('#theForm').serialize().replace('%5B%5D', '[]')
```

or this

```
$.param(obj, true);
$.post(url,serializedObj,function(){});
```

The `true` in the `$.param` indicates the traditional method of serializing an object should be used. The traditional method does not use square brackets when it encounters the same parameter name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#theForm').append('<input type="hidden" name="myField[]" id="myField[]" value="someValue" />');
```